# Converting garbled characters from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which has a tabled which has a column called 'name'

In this name for example I have a field which has the value:
`ëŒ€í•œë¯¼êµ­â€¢KOREA`

To get my table populated I had to do use an SQL file which was 99K lines big and it had the fields populated as such...

Now is there any way I can make my PHP script work so that it gives me the actual representation that I need for the characters which should be `대한민국•KOREA`

I have checked my server config. Apache, PHP, mysql are all utf-8 set and ready...

***Update***

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activeclans` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `location` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `playercount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clanlevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warswon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warslost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warstied` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `activeclans`
--

INSERT INTO `activeclans` (`id`, `name`, `location`, `playercount`, `clanlevel`, `score`, `warswon`, `warslost`, `warstied`) VALUES
(1669110, 'ë²½ì¹˜ëŠ” ê³¨ë ˜ë“¤ #.#', 'South Korea', 48, 6, 21589, 44, 18, 1),
(1707076, 'THE HURRIKANEZ', 'International', 29, 5, 20241, 39, 17, 3),
(1710048, '+WARLORDS+', 'India', 42, 3, 20700, 5, 49, 0),
(1748604, 'Ø§Ù„Ø­Ø¬Ø§ÙŠØ§', 'Jordan', 40, 4, 21218, 27, 13, 2),
(1749793, 'Vindicaâž•ed', 'International', 50, 5, 22212, 32, 18, 4),
(1755056, 'Hunter hogs 101', 'United States', 44, 3, 20501, 5, 23, 2),
(1761757, 'Ø¯Ø¹Ù… ÙˆØ­Ø±Ø¨', 'Saudi Arabia', 45, 1, 22373, 0, 7, 0),
(1764157, 'tiwi warriors', 'Morocco', 49, 5, 21663, 36, 13, 3),
(1785753, 'INCAUDA VENENUM', 'France', 41, 4, 20412, 25, 8, 1),
(1797817, 'QUEENofURAGONs', 'Philippines', 49, 5, 24104, 38, 8, 1),
(1829886, 'Max clasher', 'Philippines', 43, 5, 20076, 32, 12, 0),
(1837025, 'DUCATO ACCADEMY', 'Italy', 38, 3, 22227, 12, 12, 1),
(1845435, 'shoook tower', 'Iran', 44, 4, 21531, 30, 10, 0),
(1876715, 'ç„¡è¨€', 'Japan', 48, 4, 20178, 5, 25, 0),
(343597774219, 'CLASH O'' TRASH', 'United States', 46, 1, 20790, 0, 0, 0);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

That is part of the Sql file.

My connection to the Db is as follows:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "beep", "beep", "beep");

if ($con->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
    exit();
}
?>
```

And I have this for displaying the data:

```
$table = "
<table border='1' align='center' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr>
        <td>Clan ID</td>
        <td>Clan Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Player Count</td>
        <td>Clan Level</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Wars Won</td>
        <td>Wars Lost</td>
        <td>Wars Tied</td>
    </tr>";


$clanResultQuery = "SELECT * FROM activeclans ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100";

if($activeClansResult = mysqli_query($con,$clanResultQuery)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($activeClansResult)){
        $table .="
        <tr>
            <td>".$row['id']."</td>
            <td>".$row['name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['location']."</td>
            <td>".$row['playercount']."</td>
            <td>".$row['clanlevel']."</td>
            <td>".$row['score']."</td>
            <td>".$row['warswon']."</td>
            <td>".$row['warslost']."</td>
            <td>".$row['warstied']."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}

$table .= "</table>";
```

Comment: You should verify the character encoding of the source and destination db, along with the character encoding of your SQL file. It was probably set to latin1 or similar at some point in the process.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila I can't really change the SQL file now..

Comment: What is the character encoding in the file? Does it look like proper Korean characters, or garbage characters? If it's garbage characters (and you're sure your viewer can show Korean), then I'm afraid you probably will need to generate a new SQL file that's UTF-8 (or whatever character encoding the original db used).

Comment: **"I can't really change the SQL file now"** any special reason for that ?

Comment: **Show** the table definition. **Show** the PHP code you use to make a database connection. **Also show** an example of that backup file you used to load this data.

Comment: OP has a UTF encoded text whth that strings, verbatim. He could change encoding, but it won't work: those are no more unicode characters: those are the representation of a failed conversion to a different encoding.

Comment: @PedroLobito it is already premade from premade data...

Comment: You can always try to reimport with the correct database fields.

Comment: But is there a way to change specific lines from a 99K line SQL file so that it works?

Comment: I did not find a better solution for the same problem I had time ago, other than re-encoding those characters by hand (find and replace, via regexp and a script of course). In my case it was doable, just a few accented letters. If it is corean... then I don't think this is feasible.

Comment: @Palantir it's Korean characers, Chinese, Japanese, Arabic. There's a lot like this

Comment: @shivam-paw yes I totally understand that! You should try to figure out what the wrong conversion was, and try to understand if it is possible to go back somehow. In my case, for example, it was a bad DB encoding. I.e. db was in ISO-8859-1 and PHP worked in UTF. When I recevied the dump from that DB, it was all garbled up, like yours is: an UTF file, with badly encoded UTF characters inside it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly what should I run to get the table definition? The backup file is very very big. I will try and get some specific lines though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated my post.

Comment: Try adding the following to your php file right after opening the DB connection `mysqli_set_charset ( $con , "utf8" )`. Also add the following  at the top of the php script echoing the data `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")` Let us know how it goes. Make sure you read @RiggsFolly  comment.

Comment: @PedroLobito same result..

Comment: @PedroLobito which one? I added the stuff in the OP

Comment: My guess is the text was already messed up before being inserted on the DB. I'm sorry but I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your character sets are messed up. Your data is in `latin1 (Windows-1252)` but MySQL thinks it's `UTF-8`.

It's more likely that in the past, a system using `UTF-8` has connected to MySQL using the `latin1` character set and this is how the mix up originally occurred.

Whenever connecting to a MySQL instance, it helps if the client informs MySQL what character set and collation it's using like this.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Leave that out and you may be in a world of pain when you try to migrate your database.

To fix your data, you need to export, do some replaces and import the data again - always test on a backup before trying on your live server! This will work on most linux based systems.

```
mysqldump -u _USER_ -h _HOST_ -p --add-drop-table  --default-character-set=latin1 _DNNAME_  > mydata.sql

sed -i -e 's/CHARSET=latin1/CHARSET=utf8/ig' -e 's/latin1_bin/utf8_bin/ig' -e 's/latin1_swedish_ci/utf8_general_ci/ig' -e 's/SET NAMES latin1/SET NAMES utf8/ig' -e 's/CHARACTER SET latin1/CHARACTER SET utf8/ig' mydata.sql

mysql -u _USER_ -h _HOST_ -p  _DNNAME_< mydata.sql
```

What the commands do is dump the database in it's existing form - `latin1`. Then usse `sed` to replace all statements regarding the character set of the data from `latin1` to `utf-8`. When you import, MySQL will now see the data as `utf-8` and display it as such. Remember to test on a copy first, character sets issues can be awkward to fully resolve.

When it's all done, make sure you use the `set names` command after connecting MySQL to inform the server what character set your client is working in.